# WebBrowser in WPF using MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, browser, dependency-properties, html

I am trying to open HTML file in WebBrowser window of WPF using MVVM patten.

Note: I have fixed the issues  i was getting. Now this code works as desired.

### ViewHTMLPageView.xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="MyProject.ViewHTMLPageView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Utility"
    Title="HTML Report" Height="454" Width="787"
    >
    <Grid Name="grid1">
      <WebBrowser local:WebBrowserUtility.BindableSource="{Binding ReportPage}"  />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### ViewHTMLPageViewModel.cs

```
 namespace MyProject
 {
   public class ViewHTMLPageViewModel: ViewModelBase
   {
    public ViewHTMLPageView()
    {
         //Testing html page on load 
        _reportPage = "<table border='5'><tr><td> This is sample <b> bold </b></td></tr></table>";
        OnPropertyChanged("ReportPage");
    }

    private string _reportPage;
    public string ReportPage
    {
        get
        {
            return _reportPage;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_reportPage != value)
            {
                _reportPage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ReportPage");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

### WebBrowserUtility.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Controls; 
 using System.Windows;

 namespace MyProject.Utility
 {
   public static class WebBrowserUtility
   {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSourceProperty = 
                           DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableSource", typeof(string), 
                           typeof(WebBrowserUtility), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, 
                           BindableSourcePropertyChanged));

    public static string GetBindableSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(BindableSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBindableSource(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BindableSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, 
                                                     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)o;
        webBrowser.NavigateToString((string)e.NewValue);
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In WebBrowserUtility.cs, change the following statement:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

to

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

Now, for +1 on your question, can you tell me why this fixes your problem?

Comment: I like the addition of a challenge :)

Comment: OK, your suggestion took care of error messages. 
Now I am having issue with BindableSource="{Binding WebAddress}"
It does not communicate with WebBrowserUtility.
Any suggestion?

Comment: First thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.  Last, ask another question with all the details you found.

Comment: @Will OOooo Pick me! Because OP is not using window Forms he is using WPF. lol failz. Didn't know about the Debug message for data binding. I would hope they have it for WP7 as well.